# Embed pdf file in dompdf

Tags: pdf, dompdf

I'm using the newest version of `dompdf` I just downloaded from [here](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf).

It's simple to embed image files like png like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,HERE_COMES_THE_BASE64_ENCODE" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
```

But sometimes I have a file I want to embed that's in pdf format.

Is it possible to embed and pdf file.

I tried the following the methods that exist in HTML to embed pdf files but it doesn't work. There's no error message, the page stays blank.

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,HERE_COMES_THE_BASE64_ENCODE" type="application/pdf" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></object>

<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,HERE_COMES_THE_BASE64_ENCODE" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></iframe>

<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,HERE_COMES_THE_BASE64_ENCODE" type="application/pdf" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
```

Is there any possibility to embed a pdf file in dompdf?

Or, if that isn't possible: Is it possible to attach my pdf file, as a new page?

Comment: what you want is not clear. Do you want to convert an HTML page that has a an embedded PDF to PDF using dompdf?

Comment: @canbax Exactly! Is that possible?